# Android Widget Height and Width Specifying

Tags: android, xml, widget, size

I have a problem with my 1x1 widget. I have been testing my application on my phone which is galaxy s3 and when I set the widget proportions as follows for widget_provider.xml;

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:minHeight="40dp"
android:minWidth="40dp"
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget" 
android:previewImage="@drawable/volume_on_gr"

 >

</appwidget-provider>
```

and widget.xml as;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/phone_icon"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/toggler"
            android:src="@drawable/volume_on"
            />

    </FrameLayout>
```

I get a perfectly sized widget. However on phones with smaller screens it gets cut from the edges. On s3 mini it gets cut from the left size and on nexus it got cut from the bottom. So I used fill_parent for both properties and then widget looks smaller than it should. I have all the icons sized correctly for different sizes (mdpi, hdpi etc). It feels like it is an issue of margins added by default but I cant figure out how to correct it. What I want is on every phone to look the same or similar.

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

User 1920X1080 resolution images and put them in drawable-xxhdpi folder

the images will scaled automatically according to device

Comment: @ShashidarManchu But the images I have are kind of smaller and when I use bigger ones the image will get corrupted. Any way to avoid that? Or let's say I have 512x512 images and I make them 1920x1080 since xxhdpi requires lower resolution (lower than 512 if I am correct) the corruption will resolve itself?